# What is the difference between $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i)$? Where $\alpha = \sqrt[4]{10}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

As part of a bigger problem of finding the splitting field of $(x^4-10)(x^2-20)$ I ran into the two fields given in the title. First I am trying to focus on finding the splitting field of $x^4 - 10$. Can somebody explain the relationship between the two fields in the title?

Comment: Those two fields are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're equal. To see this it suffices to notice that each contain the generators of the other, i.e. that $\alpha,i\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i)$ and $\alpha, i=\frac{i\alpha}{\alpha}\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i\alpha)$.

Comment: Let $a+bi \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)(i)$ so $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. But $a+\frac{b}{\alpha}\alpha i \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)(i\alpha)$. So $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)(i) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)(i\alpha)$.

Let $a+bi\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)(i\alpha)$ so $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. But $b\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. So $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)(i\alpha) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)(i)$. Right?